# How to improve transparent image (filtering) edge quality in Compositor?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image, transparency

In Blender 3.2 I use an Image with alpha channel as an input and I render it from the compositor.
[image]
The result image has poor edge quality compared to the original image. Can I corret this issue with some sort of setting? Or it is a bug? I checked in VSE and the result is correct. In Blender 2.79 and the result is also correct (I haven't checked all version since then though).

[image: Compositor Render]

[image]

The original image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the file (pack the image): https://blend-exchange.com/